# join multiple dataframe with reduce while one of them is empty

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 pd dataframe i want to join on common columns.

ex:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[3,5,6],'c':[1,2,5]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,3],'b':[3,5,6]})
df3=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1],'b':[3,5,6],'d':[4,5,6]})
```

i'm using `reduce`:

```
dfs=[df1,df2,df3]
final = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on=cols_common), dfs)
```

problem: one of that df could be empty. if one of them is empty this command is throwing an error.
Any suggestion?

EDIT:

The expected result is the dataframe joined. The empty dataframe should be ignored. I wonder if there's a way to do that while avoiding a for loop with try except clause.

Comment: What is the expected result when one of them is empty?

Comment: Your first dataframe raise a ValueError due to `c` has 4 elements.

Comment: check post edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need remove empty DataFrame use list comprehension with [`DataFrame.empty`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.empty.html):

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[3,5,6],'c':[1,2,5]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,3],'b':[3,5,6]})
df3=pd.DataFrame()

dfs=[df1,df2,df3]
cols_common = ['a','b']

dfs1 = [x for x in dfs if not x.empty]
final = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on=cols_common), dfs1)
print (final)
   a  b  c
0  1  3  1
1  3  6  5
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine, even if the dataframe is empty, **but** it should have the columns for the merge:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[3,5,6],'c':[1,2,5]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,3],'b':[3,5,6]})
df3=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1],'b':[3,5,6],'d':[4,5,6]})

dfs=[df1,df2,df3]
reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on=['a', 'b']), dfs)
```

output:

```
   a  b  c  d
0  1  3  1  4
```

##### with empty dataframe

```
df2b = pd.DataFrame([], columns=['a', 'b'])
dfs=[df1,df2b,df3]
reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on=['a', 'b']), dfs)
```

output:

```
   a  b  c  d
```

##### helper function to ensure columns are defined

You could use a helper function to ensure columns are defined in your dataframes (here initializing with NaNs)

```
def ensure_columns(df, columns):
    df = df.copy()
    for col in columns:
        if col not in df:
            df[col] = [float('nan')]*len(df)
    return df


df2b = pd.DataFrame([])

columns = ['a', 'b']

dfs=[df1,df2b,df3]
reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, ensure_columns(right, columns), on=columns), dfs)
```